# How to translate Redux Framework options

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, translate, redux-framework

I am currently using the Redux framework embed in my theme.

My theme only load the po and mo file using load_theme_textdomain but the translation doesn't seems to take effect for the options I created for the redux framework.

Is there anything else I need to set in my functions.php file to make the translation apply to the options I created in the options-init.php?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lead dev of Redux here.

You need to load your text-domain and before you run Redux.  ;)